# batch compare path name %1

Tags: string, batch-file, path, compare

Here's a tiny part of my batch script that does not work as soon as there is a space in the path even though I use "" around it.

```
    call :part %1

    :part
    set  _fname=%~nx1
    if "%_fname:~0,7%"=="CREATE_" (
      copy "%~1" "%appdata%\somefolder"
      goto :eof
      )
```

If I start it with something like this, everything works fine.

```
    mybatch.bat "Z:\hello_world\CREATE_abc.def"
```

When starting it like this:

```
    mybatch.bat "Z:\hello world\CREATE_abc.def"
```

I get an error like this: "world\CREATE_abc.def""==""" cannot be processed.

Any ideas?

Comment: I believe you're being way too economical in the code fragment you've shown. `PA` is no doubt on the right track, but if you are executing the batch with the parameters you claim, you'd have to be processing %2 of the dequoted string - but that's not what you've shown. The string must be being dequoted earlier in your code.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the error is actually exactly like the one shown here. There was an IF line some between which had the same problem as the one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is the parsing of %1 in the CALLed :part

try

```
 CALL :part "%~1"
```

`%~1` expands the first parameter without surrounding quotes.  And the added surrounding quotes make sure that the called label will only receive one parameter.

Comment: Jepp, that fixed it. I tried with "%1" but I somehow missed the "~" >.>
Thanks a lot =)